# Unable to create socket connection from HTML to localhost

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets

I am trying to create a socket connection between an HTML file (which I open from my laptop) to a socket server that is running on the same laptop.
To start the server I use the following code:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer();  
server.on('connection', handleConnection);

server.listen(9000, function() {  
    console.log('server listening to %j', server.address());
});

function handleConnection(conn) {  
  var remoteAddress = conn.remoteAddress + ':' + conn.remotePort;
  console.log('new client connection from %s', remoteAddress);

  conn.on('data', onConnData);
  conn.once('close', onConnClose);
  conn.on('error', onConnError);

  function onConnData(d) {
      var chunks = [];
      chunks.push(d);
      console.log('Client at  %s  says %s', remoteAddress, Buffer.concat(chunks).toString());
      conn.write(d);
  }

  function onConnClose() {
    console.log('connection from %s closed', remoteAddress);
  }

  function onConnError(err) {
    console.log('Connection %s error: %s', remoteAddress, err.message);
  }

}
```

When I am trying to connect to the server using a simple Java app it works perfectly, here is the code for the Java app:

```
public class simpleClient {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        simpleClient sC = new simpleClient();
        sC.connect();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public void connect (){
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        DataInputStream in = null;
        Socket s = null;

        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9000);
        s = new Socket();
        try {
            s.connect(sockaddr, 10 * 1000);
            s.setSoTimeout(30000);
            out = new DataOutputStream (s.getOutputStream());
            in = new DataInputStream (s.getInputStream());


            String str = "Aloha my friend.";
            out.write(str.getBytes());
            out.flush();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}    
    }
}
```

This the server log upon successful connection:

```
server listening to {"address":"::","family":"IPv6","port":9000}
new client connection from ::ffff:127.0.0.1:54669
Client at  ::ffff:127.0.0.1:54669  says Aloha my friend.
Connection ::ffff:127.0.0.1:54669 error: read ECONNRESET
connection from ::ffff:127.0.0.1:54669 closed
```

However, when I am trying to connect to the server using a script in an HTML file nothing happens. I am not able to make the connection.

The closest I got to a connection was using the following HTML script:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script>
        function sendData() {
            try {
                var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000');
                socket.on('connect', function(data) {
                    socket.emit('Hello.');
                    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
                        socket.emit('some message ...');
                    });
                });
            }
            catch(err) {
                alert('ERROR: socket.io encountered a problem:\n\n' + err);
            }
        }
sendData();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the log on the server side looked like this:

```
    server listening to {"address":"::","family":"IPv6","port":9000}
    new client connection from ::1:65397
Client at  ::1:65397  says GET /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1520412442267-4 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
connection from ::1:65397 closed
```

I am really lost in here and since I am new to the JavaScript / HTML area I don't really know what to look for and how to fix it.

The question is: What will be the best / easiest implementation of socket client on the HTML side that will allow me to send and receive data to / from the server?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: You are not actually calling the function that creates the socket connection. The browser tries to load the socket.io library from your server, because of the first script tag in your HTML code. Try loading socket.io from a CDN instead, and actually call the sendData function

Comment: @PatrickHund thank you.
Could you provide an actual example of how to do it?

Comment: I have Edited the HTML file according to what you said, see the changes. But the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The [socket.emit](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack) method expects at least two arguments, event name and the actual data. You are currently emitting an event with just a name (“Hello.”) but no data.

Since in the backend, you are listening for events named “data”, this should work:

```
socket.emit('data', 'Hello.');
```